# Where does the Document Library TITLE show up?

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

**In SharePoint 2013 where does the Title show up for a new Document?
Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of cases in which the field title is almost mandatory.

1. if you do a lookup field that looks into a document library that one is the field to be compiled because that is the one that you will be selecting in the main list (it can be also a simple copy paste of the file name)
2. putting title in photos and images helps you when you use the slide show web part since you can display the title beneath the image

Answer (score 1):

By default, no where really. It is a good idea to utilize the field as it really helps with search results rankings. It is also a wise idea to include in in views in your document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Title is like a metadata property.

You can edit the view and Add that field to display it on the UI.